# How many bytes of a WLAN packet do I have to examine to extract MAC addresses?

Tags: wireless-networking, mac-address, sniffing, 802.11

How many bytes of a 802.11 (WLAN) packet do I have to examine to be able to extract source, destination, receiver and transmitter adress from the header?

[This image](http://spacehopper.org/mirrors/www.geocities.com/backgndtest/wlan_mac_frame.jpg) suggests the header length of a WLAN packet is 20 bytes. However, there appears to be a preamble and a PLCP header.
Viewing captured packets with Wireshark reveals that there's a Radiotap header (34 or 37 bytes long in my file), and a MAC header of more than 20 bytes.

How many bytes (the absolute minimum) do I have to capture in order to (always) be able to extract the four MAC addresses in the MAC header (802.11g/n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This image suggests the header length of a WLAN packet is 20 bytes.

No, it suggests that the WLAN *header* is *30* bytes long.  More accurately, it's *up to* 30 bytes long, although not all packets have all four MAC address fields, so the header *can* be shorter.  (It can also be longer, with QoS and 802.11n-and-later HT Control fields, but those come *after* the MAC addresses.)

So, as Spiff indicates, you need to capture at least 30 bytes to be certain that you'll get all the MAC addresses.

> However, there appears to be a preamble and a PLCP header.

Those don't appear in the capture.

> Viewing captured packets with Wireshark reveals that there's a Radiotap header (34 or 37 bytes long in my file),

Yes, if your packets have a Radiotap header, you have to capture that in addition to the 802.11 header, and the length of the Radiotap header is, as Spiff notes, dependent on the hardware, the driver, and the way the packet is received or transmitted.

So, *IF* it's possible to do so, you should capture only with the 802.11 header.  This might or might not be possible, depending on which OS you're using (*BSD and OS X should let you capture only with 802.11 headers, Linux might only let you get Radiotap headers).

> and a MAC header of more than 20 bytes.

Yes, as indicated, the diagram in question does *not* suggest that the header is (at most) 20 bytes long.

Answer (score 1):

Select 802.11 as your interface data type (DLT_IEEE802_11) and capture 30 bytes.

If you really want to capture the minimal amount and reliably capture Address 1 through Address 4, then you shouldn't use the Radiotap (DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO) radio metadata capture type because it's a variable-length header. How long it is can depend on the radio and driver and various aspects of the physical transmission and reception of the packet.